# Windows recognizes external HDMI display but outputs no video signal

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

My laptop no longer outputs video through the HDMI port, but Windows does correctly recognize that there's a monitor plugged in and even knows the model, resolution, refresh rate, etc. I don't use the HDMI out too often, but I know for certain that it worked a few months ago.

I can position the external display (in extended desktop mode) as if everything was working, but there's no image on the display. The monitor (HP 24F) says "No video signal" on screen.

I've done all the usual troubleshooting stuff... different plug-in sequences (e.g. start laptop first and then plug in display... that kind of thing), changed the resolution, refresh rate, made sure that all drivers are up to date. Double-checked that the monitor is in HDMI. I also confirmed that the cable and the monitor are working using another computer.

As it's been some months since I last had it working, there's been a bunch of Windows updates and driver updates. Windows correctly recognizes the display, so I'm hoping that this is a software thing and not something physically wrong with the HDMI port.

This is an Asus ROG Strix (G531GT). This model has an NVIDIA GeForce 1650 GPU (as well as an integrated Intel GPU), Windows 10, BIOS 308... if any of that is helpful. All drivers are up to date.

I'm open to any ideas or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

As a method rather than a solution:

You can try testing the problematic system and each of its parts with different combinations and tools.

This can allow you to rule out a possible half-defective, cracked, worn component.
What I'm trying to explain, for example: An HDMI cable can be both broken and working, sometimes it transmits from a broken point, and sometimes it doesn't.

The only way I know of to eliminate this is the method I mentioned.

You can test the HDMI cable with another display and - or - a different output device than the one you are currently using.

If necessary, apply this test to other components with the same logic,
You may be able to capture the superposition -joking- situation that is often seen in cable, etc equipment.

Answer (score 0):

There is an NVIDIA control panel that you can use to tweak the external monitor settings (search for NVIDIA should locate it from Windows menu). For me this worked while the Windows "Display Settings" control panel did not.